# How to disable approximation in HighchartJS?

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts, approximation

I have this now:

I need to draw graph of this function:

```
-3.6 * Math.exp(-3.5 * Math.pow(x, 2)) * Math.sign(Math.cos(31 * x - 7));
```

I decided to use HighchartJS. There are no problems with it, but I am not sure, that it is correct to approximate function (highchartJS does this).

You can find my results [here, on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2kSf/13/).

You can see, that values of the graph are "jumping" with some amplitude, highchartJS approx it and I am getting continious line. Actually, graph of my function differs from this result. You can see that [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-3.6*exp%28-3.5*x%5E2%29*sign%28cos%2831*x-7%29%29%20from%20-1%20to%201), for example.

Also, you can see the result on image below:

[image]

Line is interrupting. The question is how I can get same result with highchartJS (or maybe I should use another library?) ?

If graph is not running on Chrome try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q2kSf/18/), please

Comment: The linked jsfiddle does not run.

Comment: @wergeld it does. In chrome 37, at least.

Comment: I am using chrome 37 as well. http://jsfiddle.net/q2kSf/13/ gets error that undefined is not a function in your foo() func.

Comment: FF 32.0.3 works perfectly :(

Comment: "undefined is not a function".... I am not using `undefined` anythere :)

Comment: Can you try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/q2kSf/18/)?

Comment: @wergeld, pretty weird, have you tried it in incognito mode?

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all, you are using `Math.sign` method which is not part of official standards (just draft). Simply add your method to get working example in chrome:

```
Math.sign = function(x){
  if( +x === x ) { 
    return (x === 0) ? x : (x > 0) ? 1 : -1;
  }
  return NaN;
}
```

Now, The problem is that Highcharts connects all points with lines. In your case better solution is to use `scatter` type - since you have enough points to display expected result: http://jsfiddle.net/q2kSf/22/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        name: 'Values',
        data: data,
        marker: {
            radius: 2   
        }
    }]
});
```